# How to set Client info in Spark JDBC as we can do in Connection setClientInfo

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc

When using Java/Scala java.sql.Connection I am able to add some client info on top of my connection For example:

```
  val con: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcHelper.finalUrl, jdbcHelper.getUser, jdbcHelper.getPass)
  con.setClientInfo("ClientName", "JobAppStateManager")
  con.prepareStatement(SOME_STATEMENT) 
  .....
```

Now I would like to add my info to Spark jdbc connection ?

```
 val opts =  Map(
  "url" -> finalUrl,
  "user" -> user,
  "password" -> password,
  "dbtable" -> tableName
)
val df = sqlContext.
  read.
  format("jdbc").
  options(opts).load
```

Is it possible in a clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not currently possible in a clean way; `spark-redshift` does not add that property: 
https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/blob/8adfe95a25d6bbe8aedc2010a756ccf3615eab24/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/redshift/RedshiftJDBCWrapper.scala#L228

However, there is a difficult workaround: create your own JDBC Driver wrapper that overrides the `driver.connect(url, properties)` function to add the property you want. Then tell spark to use it by calling `Class.forName(my.package.Driver)` before using Spark on Redshift.

Comment: is it still not possible to pass on the client info?